# Instantiate View Controller With Identifier return nil?

Tags: xcode, swift2, viewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers( Dialer, Audio and Call View Controller) , Dialer and Audio only it's connected to layouts and Call it's calling through Audio View , When I'm clicking on callButton in Dialer View Controller I must passing value to CallViewController and then directly call the AudioViewController that have StoryBoardID (AudioViewController) but I don't know this line return null so I can not move to the AudioViewController .

```
callViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AudioCallViewController") as! AudioCallViewController
```

Complete Code :

Dialer View:

```
class DialerViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var progNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progNumberLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onConnectionStatusNotification:", name: NOTIFICATION_PHONE_EVENT, object: nil)

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityMonitoringEnabled = false
}



@IBAction func makeCallButton(sender: AnyObject) {



    let ownNumber = AppDelegate.sharedInstance().phone?.config().regUser
    if !ownNumber!.isEmpty || progNumberLabel.text != ownNumber {

        var callViewController: CallViewController?

            callViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AudioCallViewController") as! AudioCallViewController     //Exception in this line 


        callViewController?.number = progNumberLabel.text
        //self.presentedViewController(callViewController,  animated:true, completion:nil)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(callViewController!, animated: true)
    }


}



func onConnectionStatusNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let status = PhoneEvents(rawValue: notification.object!.integerValue)
    let _ = status! == .RegSuccess
}



deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

}
```

CallView:

```
class CallViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var number: String?
var callId: Int?
var incoming: Bool?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("The Number is" + number!)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onConnectionStatusNotification:", name: NOTIFICATION_PHONE_EVENT, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onCallNotification:", name: NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT, object: nil)


}

func closeView() {
    if self == navigationController?.topViewController {
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}

func onCallNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

}

func onConnectionStatusNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

}



deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

}
```

AudioViewController:

```
class AudioCallViewController: CallViewController {

 ............. 

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
callViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AudioCallViewController") as! AudioCallViewController     //Exception in this line
```

In above, you did not declare what `storyboard` is, so it will definitely return null

by default, your storyboard should be `Main`, so add in this code just above that statement

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: I will try that and reply to you again